# What actor based web frameworks are available for Scala?

Tags: scala, frameworks, actor

I need to build very concurrent web service which will expose REST based API for JavaScript (front end) and Rails (back end). Web service will be suiting data access API to MongoDB.

I already wrote an initial implementation using NodeJS and would like to try Scala based solution. I'm also considering Erlang, for which every web framework is actor based.

So I'm looking for web framework explicitly build using Actors in order to support massive load of requests I'm very new to Scala and I don't quite understand how Actor might work if almost all frameworks for Scala are based on Java servlets which creates a thread on each request which will just exhaust all resources in my scenario.

Comment: This is an old question but you should look at Play 2.0 which will run on netty and use akka.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If you're really going to have 10k+ long active connections at a time, then any standard Java application server/framework (maybe, except for Netty) will not work for you - all of them are consuming lots of memory (even if any kind of smart NIO is used). You'd better stick to a clustered event-loop based solution (like node.js that you've already tried), mongrel backed with zeroMQ, nginx with the mode for writing into MQ polled by Scala Actors, etc.
2. Among the Scala/Java frameworks, Lift has a good async support for REST (though it's not directly tied to actors). OTOH, LinkedIn uses Scalatra + stdlib actors for their REST services behind Signal ,and feels just fine.

Comment: Thanks, the connections wont be long, but they will be around 10k pretty easy. I tried to understand how Lift works and I don't like they idea having sessions all other the place. Sinatra/ExpressJS/Scalatra are more preferable solutions for me because of their simplicity. You mentioned how LinkedIn used Scalatra - but they stated 'Scalatra doesn't use any actors' which is a pity.

Comment: 1. Lift CometActors and async REST has nothing to do with sessions (both are tending to be stateless). 2. The fact that Scalatra doesn't use actors the way Lift does (e.g. like CometActor) doesn't stop anyone from using actors in conjunction with + from what I know, Scalatra developers are working on COMET support now

Comment: Thanks for explaining how Lift works. Regarding Scalatra and actors - will Scalatra die under heavy load because it will be creating new thread for every request because of it default implementation extending standart java class (seems github.com is not responding in this part of the world so I can look what class exactly Scalatra extends)?

Comment: `ScalatraServlet` extends standard `HttpServlet`, so, roughly, handling of 10k connections will eat ~2gb RAM. If the memory is a problem for you, whilst you want to stick to Java ecosystem, you should forget about tight integration with actors at least for now (and pick `Netty`, `Mina`, or a more high-level `Atmosphere`).

Comment: You may find this interesting: http://www.jboss.org/netty/performance/20090607-asalihefendic.html

Answer (score 1):

Another option is [Play framework](http://www.playframework.org/). The latest 1.1 release supports Scala. It also supports akka as a module.

Comment: I believe the new 2.0 of Play will have actor support through akka and will use netty.

Answer (score 1):

As far as Scalatra itself, they have been working on a new request 
abstraction called SSGI (akin to the Servlet/Rack/WSGI/WAI layer), 
that they said should ennable them to break from solely running as a 
Servlet and also run on top of something built with Netty.  See thread [here](http://groups.google.com/group/scalatra-user/msg/cf58882b4ab72cb6).
http://github.com/scalatra/ssgi

There's some other interesting frameworks at the Scalatra level of simplicity since designed from the ground up to support asynchronous web services (won't tie up a thread per request):

https://github.com/jdegoes/blueeyes - Not a servlet; built on Netty. 
("loosely inspired by ...  Scalatra")

http://spray.cc/ - Built on Akka actors, Akka Mist. Servlet 3.0 or Jetty continuations 
("spray was heavily inspired by BlueEyes and Scalatra.")

And at a lower level: 
https://github.com/rschildmeijer/loft - "Continuation based non-blocking, asynchronous, single threaded web 
server."
Not production-ready, but rather interesting-looking.  Continuations require the compiler plugin.

Answer (score 0):

http://liftweb.net/ Indeed, a request starts off as a servlet, but then lift uses comet support found in many servlet containers to break away from the thread, keeping the request context (which the container then doesn't destroy) which then can be used to output data in actors.

http://akkasource.org also has support for rest, but it will block the thread until the actor finishes with its work

Comment: Does anything lighter what lift exist for Scala? I like Sinatra (or ExpressJS) and I was very exited to know that port of Sinatra (Scalatra) also exists for Scala but seems it doesn't use Actors

Comment: Well, as mentioned, Akka has REST and Actors. It has in-progress comet support by integrating the atmosphere library. For my use case, atmosphere was not good (all I could figure was how to do chat-like services with it, not 'start'->'spawn actor'->'finish' cycles)

Comment: Akka has a Comet module underway codenamed akka-mist that will probably do what you need -> accept incoming request, dispatch it to an actor, have the actor fulfill the request asynchronously.